Python CLI commands compiled into script
Is there a simple way of converting the sequence of commands I ran in the Python CLI session into a script?
I use CLI to create logic before actually writing the script. I use CLI to avoid repetitive queries to network that take a couple of seconds, this makes testing the script slower than writing the logic on CLI directly.
After I am done on CLI, I usually trace-back my logic using the up arrow to see the sequence of commands I executed. Is there a way for me to directly get a python file that has all of my commands from the current session?
